# compressing files to .h5

Tags: python, pandas, h5py

I have a .h5 file from which I read some data, I order it in some way and then I save it to another .h5 file. Here is my code:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

f = pd.read_hdf("input_file.h5")

dt = f.values

dt2 = np.transpose(np.transpose(dt)[0:2100])
dt3 = np.transpose(np.transpose(dt)[-1])
dt3 = dt3.reshape(1,len(dt3))

d2 = len(dt2[0])
d1 = len(dt2)

dt2 = dt2.reshape((len(dt2), len(dt2[0])//3, 3))
ordered_index = np.flip(dt2[:,:,0].argsort(),1)

dt2 = dt2[np.arange(len(dt2[:,:,0].argsort()))[:,None],ordered_index].reshape((d1,d2))
dt2 = np.transpose(dt2)

data = np.transpose(np.concatenate((dt2,dt3),axis=0))

df=pd.DataFrame(data=data[0:,0:], index=[i for i in range(data.shape[0])], columns=[str(i) for i in range(data.shape[1])])


hf = h5py.File('ordered_pt_data.h5', 'w')
hf.create_dataset('dataset_ordered_pt', data=df)
hf.close()
```

The program runs fine, and when I print the new data (i.e. `print(df)`) everything looks well (i.e. the data is ordered the way I want) and the ordered data has the same dimension as the input data. However the input file "input_file.h5" has 2.6GB while the file I create has 18GB. What am I doing wrong? Do i need to pass some extra parameter to compress the data more? Again, the output file contains the exactly same data (both size and type, unless something I did changed the type of the data without me realizing it) as the input file, just in a different order. Thank you!

Comment: Do they have the same data types?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel I am not sure. The code I posted above is the whole code I use. I am not sure if the data type gets changed somewhere along the way, but I didn't change it on purpose.

Comment: I'd also check data type first. Besides that - are you sure that your data juggling does exactly what you want? Don't get me wrong, for anyone else but you this is almost crypto science anyway, but if I set `dt = np.random.random((2100, 30))` for testing purpose, the output `data` is of shape `(2100, 31)`. Not that this causes the 18GB, just wanted to hint...

Comment: Try `f.dtypes == df.dtypes` or manually `print(f.dtypes) ;print(df.dtypes)`

Comment: You can read each file in with h5py (`hin = h5py.File('input_file.h5', 'r')`and `hout = h5py.File('ordered_pt_data.h5', 'r')`) and then print a dataset like `hout['dataset_ordered_pt']` (for getting a dataset name of the input file you could check `hin.keys()`). The feedback should show you the datatype like `<HDF5 dataset ......, type "<f8">`, where `"<f8"` stands for a 64bit floating value.

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel This is the output I am getting: `0       float64
1       float64
2       float64
3       float64
4       float64
         ...
2096    float64
2097    float64
2098    float64
2099    float64
2100    float64
Length: 2101, dtype: object
0       float64
1       float64
2       float64
3       float64
4       float64
         ...
2096    float64
2097    float64
2098    float64
2099    float64
2100    float64
Length: 2101, dtype: object`

Answer (score 1):

You can begin debugging by seeing if data types are the same:

```py
# ...

print('f dtypes and memory usage')
print(f.info(memory_usage='deep'))


print('df dtypes and memory usage')
print(df.info(memory_usage='deep'))
```

Check the memory usage:

```py
# ...
print('f memory usage')
print(f.memory_usage(deep=True)

print('df memory')
print(df.memory_usage(deep=True))
```

If everything is the same, namely same data types, same numbers of rows and columns. Then the issue is compression.

Per documentation you can compress your data as follows

```py
with h5py.File('ordered_pt_data.h5', 'w') as hf:
    hf.create_dataset('dataset_ordered_pt', data=df, compression="gzip", compression_opts=9)
```

See: [doc](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html) for more options and details

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The output is identical for both, so I assume it is a matter of compression. Any suggestion on what I should do?

Comment: Is it likely to get a compression factor 7 of binary data?

Comment: Can you share  the outputs of `x.info(memory='deep')`?

Comment: Updated my answer to include compression